Multi-objective optimisation methods suitable for LPs and (M)ILPs
Which methods (classic/modern) are utilised to solve multi-objective optimisation problems compatible with linear programming (LP) and mixed-integer linear programming.
Utilised in the context of time - still utilised.
E.g. I assume that $\epsilon$-constraint method is mostly replaced by the augmented $\epsilon$-constraint method.

One approach is lexicographic ordering of the objectives. The most important objective is optimized with co compromises. The second most important objective is optimized subject to doing no worse than optimal in the highest priority objective, and so on. This of course requires the user to believe that each objective is unambiguously more important than certain others.
In the context of MIP, the implementation seems to be pretty straightforward. In branch-and-bound with a single objective, when a new incumbent is found you prune any node with objective value worse than or equal to the value of the new incumbent (give or take numerical tolerance). With lexicographic ordering, you only prune nodes when the new incumbent dominates them (equally good on the first $n-1$ objectives, better on the $n$-th).
